# How to display a frame with GUI intelliJ

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, frame

I am using IntelliJ GUI feature and I am struggling to display the frame.

Here is a picture of my GUI components:

[image]

And here is the code I used to configure it in my IDE:

```
public class SftpDoc extends JPanel{

private JRadioButton radioButton1;
private JRadioButton radioButton2;
private JRadioButton radioButton3;
private JButton button1;
private JComboBox comboBox1;
private JTextField textField1;
private JButton browseButton;
private JButton button2;
private final static JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public SftpDoc(){

    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(comboBox1);
    panel.add(radioButton1);
    panel.add(textField1);
    panel.add(browseButton);
    panel.add(radioButton2);
    panel.add(radioButton3);
    panel.add(button2);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}
}
```

When I run the class the frame is the only component that appears:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to maximize the window or set the frame size in the code - frame.setSize()

Comment: If you use frame.pack(), it will automatically change the size of the frames according to the size of components in it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I tried adding that but it still shows that there is nothing within the frame.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it to run and show everything. Instead of extending JPanel I used JFrame and called the class to be set visible. The code is as follow:

```
public class SftpDoc extends JFrame {

private JRadioButton radioButton1;
private JRadioButton radioButton2;
private JRadioButton radioButton3;
private JButton button1;
private JComboBox comboBox1;
private JTextField textField1;
private JButton browseButton;
private JButton button2;
private final static JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public SftpDoc() {

    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(comboBox1);
    panel.add(radioButton1);
    panel.add(textField1);
    panel.add(browseButton);
    panel.add(radioButton2);
    panel.add(radioButton3);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.revalidate();
    add(panel);
    pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SftpDoc().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Hi, you have to add frame.pack(); before setVisible() method.